# Prevent ActionMailer to strip repeating spaces in plain message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whitespace, actionmailer, ascii-art

I'm trying to have an table in text mail, so I write some helpers:

```
module MailerHelper
  def field_width(text, width)
    ' ' * (width - text.length) + text
  end

  def cell(text, width)
    output = '| ' + field_width(text, width-2) + " |\n"
    output << '+-' + '-'*(width-2) + '-+'
  end
end
```

Then in view I write it like this:

```
<%= cell 'Test', 10 %>
```

But that what I get (according to `letter_opener`) is:

```
| Test |
+----------+
```

As can you see, the spaces that are repeating before `Test`. My question is how to prevent ActionMailer (or anything else what is destroying my beautiful table) from doing that.

Mailer code:

```
  def remind(client, invoices)
    @client = client
    @company = @client.company
    @invoices  = invoices.to_a

    days_left = @invoices.first.pay_date - Date.today
    message = @client.group.messages.find_by_period days_left.to_i

    raise 'No messages for this invoices.' if message.nil?

    @template = message.template || if days_left < 0
      t 'message.before'
    elsif days_left > 0
      t 'message.after'
    else
      t 'message.today'
    end

    @text = liquid_parse @template
    @html = markdown_parse @text

    mail(:to => @client.email, :subject => t('message.title'))
  end

  private
    def markdown_parse(text)
      markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new Redcarpet::Render::HTML,
        :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true
      markdown.render text
    end

    def liquid_parse(text)
      renderer = Liquid::Template.parse text
      renderer.render 'company' => @company, 'invoice' => @invoice, 'client' => @client
    end
```

Comment: Time to crack open the ActionMailer source code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found bug. It was caused by Premailer what I use to inline CSS in HTML part.

```
class InlineCSSInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    #message.text_part.body = Premailer.new(message.text_part.body.to_s, with_html_string: true).to_plain_text # this is line causing the problem.
    message.html_part.body = Premailer.new(message.html_part.body.to_s, with_html_string: true).to_inline_css
  end
end

Mailer.register_interceptor InlineCSSInterceptor
```